# Two levels of contains in an XPath

Tags: xpath, contains

I have this XPath:

```
//tr[contains(td, 'Europe')]
```

which was working when I had this:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>Europe</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

but now I have this:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><a>Europe</a></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

How can I get  with an XPath now (based on the fact that Europe is in there).

I tried:

```
//tr[contains(a, "Europe")]
```

and

```
//tr[contains(text(), "Europe")]
```

and many other silly things without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//tr[contains(td, 'Europe')]
```

This should work with both schema because `fn:contains()` cast both arguments to strings.

I do see a problem with a different schema where there can be more than one `td` element. For that case you should use:

```
//tr[td[contains(.,'Europe')]]
```

Comment: Yes, there are more tds in there, I'll fix the question, thanks for the answer.

Comment: You may want .//tr[td[contains(.,'Europe')]] if there is any chance this could also match outside the context node.